# Tomcat 7 using high cpu with NIO connector

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, nio, comet

I implemented a comet server with tomcat 7 and the NIO connector. The cpu usage is always around 1% but sometimes (even after days) the cpu rises to 100% and remain fixed to that value even without any requests to process.
I used `jstack` to get the state of the threads and pasted the output here:

[jstack output](http://pastebin.com/sKJcQkei)

can anybody point me in the right direction? Any idea about where I should look?

Comment: Does it happen if you use BIO?

Comment: I didn't try since the tomcat docs specify that comet should be used with NIO. In my application there may be up to 10000 concurrent active connections, would BIO be able to handle them?

Comment: NIO is the right choice for your scenario, but checking whether the BIO connector solves the problem helps identify what the solution might be. What exact version of Tomcat 7 are you using? What do your thread dumps tell you about what is going on inside the JVM? You will need to dump Comet in favor of Servlet-Async in the future, btw.